# Dynamically switching JQuery themes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, themes, themeroller

If I download multiple JQuery themes how can I give the users of my web application the ability to dynamically switch between themes?

Comment: Are you customizing the themes?  If not the themeswitcher widget is available: http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/ThemeSwitcher

Comment: I think that's exactly what I need, thanks.
I can't accept your answer, is that because it's a comment and not an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick Craver's comment was correct, the themeswitcher widget was ideal:
<s>http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/ThemeSwitcher</s>
new link: https://github.com/harborhoffer/Super-Theme-Switcher

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the themeswitcher, you can do change the theme dynamically by removing the links to the current theme.  Add new links with the new theme.
This enjoys the advantage that you can change also your own themes.

See below for an Ansatz

```
<head>
<link href="./jquery-ui-first/jquery-ui.css" id="qtheme" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="./css/specials-first.css" id="mtheme" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Now consider to change the theme upon a button clicked :

```
$(#otherthemebutton).click(function(){
    $("#qtheme").remove();
    $("#mtheme").remove();
    qelem = loadCss("./jquery-ui-other/jquery-ui.css","qtheme");
    qelem = loadCss("./css/specials-other.css","mtheme");
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(qelem);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(melem);
});

loadCss = function(filename,id) {
    var elem=document.createElement("link");
    elem.id=id;
    elem.rel="stylesheet";
    elem.type="text/css";
    elem.href=filename;
    return elem;
}
```

You need to ensure that the underlying (external) javascript is for the same version.